# Cannot use Thunderbird properly with proxy setting

Tags: skype, thunderbird, proxy, email

My laptop is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After setting the proxy in the system level, the softeware center and chrome browser can work well. But Thunderbird cannot. No matter what is the proxy setting in Thunderbird( auto-proxy, system proxy, manual setting), I cannot login my email box. I tried the gmail and my working email account, both failed. I am sure there is no fault in the email setting. 
But, it is wired that I can download the "add-on" in Thunderbird. And, as the software have similar setting, firefox can work well with all these setting. And, the skype can only login through the "skype name" option, "microsoft account" not working.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there's something wrong with https support.
If the proxy is set to relay https traffic while it can't handle it then you'll have no connection.
What happens if you try to go to https://www.google.com with firefox while the proxy is set? Note that the link above says https (so ending with 's')

Comment: I can visit this website well. It seems not this problem